# C# - Creating HTML reports

Tags: c#, html, reporting

I have in my winform application 4 datasets that gets values from my database. Values like like how many products I have in my product table and information about categories. I was wondering how I can save the dataset informaiton in a html page. I want to create a html template so that I can present the information in nice way. How can I do that? Eny good guide that explains how to do that?

Answer (score 7):

This seems like a great job for something like [RazorEngine](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/). You can define a template using Razor syntax, and then render out the content using the RazorEngine template service, e.g.:

```
@helper RenderItem(Item item) {
  <tr>
    <td>item.Name</td>
    <td>item.Price</td>
  </tr>
}

<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <table>
      @foreach (Item item in Model.Items) {
        @RenderItem(item)
      }
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can save DataSet as `XML` and then transform it by using [`XSLT`](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/).

You can take a look at this samples:

- [XSLT - Transformation](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_transformation.asp)
- [Creating and Populating an HTML Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms912465.aspx)
- [Using XSLT and .NET to Manipulate XML Files](http://www.xmlfiles.com/articles/cynthia/xslt/default.asp)

Answer (score 1):

I personally recommend generating HTML with Linq to Xml (using System.Xml.Linq)

You don't even have to use the strict XHTML schema's, but you'll get heap s of mileage out of Xml.Linq. Here is a snippet from my own code bases:

```
    #region Table Dump Implementation

    private static XNode Dump<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, IEnumerable<string> header, params Func<T, string>[] columns)
    {
        if (!items.Any())
            return null;

        var html = items.Aggregate(new XElement("table", new XAttribute("border", 1)),
            (table, item) => { 
                table.Add(columns.Aggregate(new XElement("tr"),
                    (row, cell) => { 
                        row.Add(new XElement("td", EvalColumn(cell, item)));
                        return row; 
                    } ));
                return table;
            });

        html.AddFirst(header.Aggregate(new XElement("tr"),
            (row, caption) => { row.Add(new XElement("th", caption)); return row; }));

        return html;
    }

    private static XNode EvalColumn<T>(Func<T, string> cell, T item)
    {
        var raw = cell(item);
        try
        {
            var xml = XElement.Parse(raw);
            return xml;
        }
        catch (XmlException)
        {
            return new XText(raw);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Dot Diagrams

    public void LinkDiagram(Digraph graph, string id)
    {
        if (!graph.AllNodes.Any())
            return;
        var img = Path.GetFileName(GenDiagramFile(graph, _directory, id));

        _body.Add(
            new XElement("a",
                new XAttribute("href", img),
                new XElement("h4", "Link naar: " + graph.name),
                        new XElement("img",
                            new XAttribute("border", 1),
                            new XAttribute("src", img),
                            new XAttribute("width", "40%"))));
    }
```

**Note that is it exceedingly easy to use inline HTML text as well** (as long as it is valid XML), using a helper like so:

```
    public void GenericAppend(string content)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(content))
            _body.Add(XElement.Parse(content));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is pretty easy so you may just want to generate html directly and use some pre-created CSS for the styling. However if you want something more sophisticated, please take a look at [Windward Reports](https://www.windwardstudios.com/programming-languages/csharp).